# Can't print PDF from <object> / <iframe> / <embed> in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, pdf, firefox, iframe, printing

I have the following React component. It receives a link to a PDF document and renders PDF browser-specific viewer.

```
export type PDFViewerChildrenProps = {
  dataUrl: string;
};
 
const PDFViewerChildren = (props: PDFViewerChildrenProps) => {
  const { dataUrl } = props;
 
  if (!dataUrl) {
    return null;
  }
 
  return (
    <object
      type="application/pdf"
      aria-label="View PDF"
      data={dataUrl}
    />
  );
};
 
export default PDFViewerChildren;
```

It works as intended in all browsers except Firefox. Firefox for some reason fails to print the document. Each time a “Print” button on viewer’s toolbar is clicked, an NS_ERROR_FAILURE error appears in the console (see screenshot).

[link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Crh.png)

Other buttons work as intended. The PDF itself is rendered correctly. The only issue is printing in Firefox.

The same error appears in Firefox even if object is replaced with iframe or embed.

Tried rewriting component with different tags, adjusting Firefox setting - nothing worked

Comment: I've debugged PDF viewer and noticed that the error occurs when viewer's even bus fails to dispatch "print" event. Event handler calls window.print()
Just wondering if there's a circumstance when Firefox doesn't allow to call window.print()